# Argparse: optional subparsers with store_true flags

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

Forgive me if my terminology is off, but I'm looking for a way to add a subparser to an optional argparse argument, with `store_true` flags on each of the args.

Ideally, I'd like to use the following syntax to reference the boolean value of `--html` in the `shodan_parser` subparser:

```
if args.shodan.html:
    print("Doing a thing")
```

---

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r", "--reverse-dns", help="rDNS on host", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--shodan", help="perform SHODAN query on discovered IPs", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("targets", help="IPv4 addresses to search for", nargs="+")

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
shodan_parser = subparsers.add_parser("shodan", help="SHODAN options")
shodan_parser.add_argument("--html", action="store_true")
shodan_parser.set_defaults(which='shodan')
```

---

Output:

```
(venv)[nott@admin gumdrop]$ python gumdrop.py google.ca --shodan --html
usage: gumdrop.py [-h] [-r] [-e] [-s] targets [targets ...] {shodan} ...
gumdrop.py: error: too few arguments

(venv)[nott@admin gumdrop]$ python gumdrop.py --shodan --html google.ca askjeeves.ca
usage: gumdrop.py [-h] [-r] [-e] [-s] targets [targets ...] {shodan} ...
gumdrop.py: error: invalid choice: 'askjeeves.ca' (choose from 'shodan')
```

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: Python 2 right? Could you post the expected output based on command line arguments you plan on providing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by expected output. I want to be able to set a boolean flag for `shodan.html`, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Could you then provide an example of the command line arguments you want to enter?

Comment: `python module.py --shodan -h` it could get messy though. I'm not sure how else I'd handle it though.

Comment: Just so you know, you won't be able to do -h because it conflicts with the argparse default -h for help. So you will have to do --html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r", "--reverse-dns", help="rDNS on host", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--shodan", help="perform SHODAN query on discovered IPs", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("targets", help="IPv4 addresses to search for", nargs="+")
```

Does this `--shodan` optional (flag) have anything to do with the subparser name?  What is its purpose?  Are you confusing a flag with a subparser?

The subparser is also a positional.  Using both a positional with `nargs='+'` and a subparser might work, but is likely to cause confusion.  When does the list of `targets` end, and the subparser (and its arguments) begin?

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
shodan_parser = subparsers.add_parser("shodan", help="SHODAN options")
...
```

your output

```
(venv)[nott@admin gumdrop]$ python gumdrop.py google.ca --shodan --html
....
```

I'm guessing that this sets `targets=['google.ca']`, `shodan=True`.  But you haven't given it a subparser command.  The `--html` is an unknown.

```
(venv)[nott@admin gumdrop]$ python gumdrop.py --shodan --html google.ca askjeeves.ca
...
```

Now you set `shodan=True` (the main parser flag).  Again `--html` is unknown.  It sets `target=['google.ca']`.  But now it tries to interpret `askjeeves.ca` as a subparser command .  But it does not match the available choices.

I think these lines would work:

```
python gumdrop.py google.ca askjeeves.ca shodan --html
python gumdrop.py --shodan google.ca shodan --html
```

I'd suggest dropping the whole subparser bit.  It's just confusing things, for you and your users. Go ahead and include `--html` in the main parser.  It's optional, so it can be used, or ignored, at will.  It you must use subparsers, review the documentation, and try some simpler examples.

As for getting `args.shodan.html`, that's a much more advanced issue, involving the nesting of namespaces.  For now be happy if you get `args.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the switch from "-h" to something else (or disable the help), because the "-h" switch is already used by the help menu

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r", "--reverse-dns", help="rDNS on host", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-s", "--shodan", help="perform SHODAN query on discovered IPs", action="store_true")parser.add_argument("targets", help="IPv4 addresses to search for", nargs="+")

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
shodan_parser = subparsers.add_parser("shodan", help="SHODAN options")
shodan_parser.add_argument("--html", action="store_true")
shodan_parser.set_defaults(which='shodan')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.html:
    print("Doing a thing")
```

Comment: Updated my question with the result(s) of running the script with args.html as a conditional.